# If column have a row=$variable and in another column on the same row=$variable2 return value 1

Tags: php

Sorry for confusing title. But I don't know how to explain this.(I don't speak that good English)

Here is a picture to make it alittle bit more clear:

http://img823.imageshack.us/img823/8812/edxt.png

If pic_name=328.jpg AND user=myhrmans return value of 1
else if you cant find value user=myhrmans return 0 for example. Anyway I can pull this off?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand precisely what you mean, but I'm going to make an attempt.

Your query should be written somehow like this one:

```
SELECT user, pic_name,
    IF(user = 'myhrmans' AND pic_name = '328.jpg', 1, 0) AS value
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE user = myhrmans;
```

When executed from PHP (and after fetching the values), your query will return this array:

```
$result = array(
    0 => array(
        'user' => 'myhrmans',
        'pic_name' => '326.jpg',
        'value' => 0
    ),
    1 => array(
        'user' => 'myhrmans',
        'pic_name' => '329.jpg',
        'value' => 0
    ),
    2 => array(
        'user' => 'myhrmans',
        'pic_name' => '328.jpg',
        'value' => 1
    ),
    3 => array(
        'user' => 'myhrmans',
        'pic_name' => '319.jpg',
        'value' => 0
    )
);
```

Which, if I understood, approaches what you want.

Comment: I think this is what I want. If I type this: $likedbefore=  $row3['value'];
Will I get 1 if I write echo $likedbefore if there is a value with 1?

Comment: Hum. Actually... No. You have to look for the place in the array where `value` is 1. You can't guess it from the start, otherwise it wouldn't need looking in the db.

Comment: Okey. Is there anyway I can pull this of? I need to check this in a if statement in PHP.